# Redirect Default Domain Access and Non-Existent Links to 404 Page with Specific Conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, cgi-bin

I have a website, and by default, it runs in the `cgi-bin` directory. However, there seems to be an issue in my configuration. When I enter a directory or file that doesn't exist on the system, it redirects to `/cgi-bin/index.cgi` instead of redirecting to the `404.html` page, as it should. Only when I enter a link like `example.com/errorlink.pm` does it redirect to the `404.html` error page. This is the specific configuration for each section, including `.htaccess` and Apache2:

`.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_CGI_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteRule ^webdav /cgi-bin/webdav.cgi [L]
RewriteRule ^api/(\w+)/(\w+)$ /cgi-bin/xapi.cgi [L]
RewriteRule \.pm$ /404.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Apache2 config:

```
<VirtualHost IP:8443>

    ServerName localhost
    
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/domains/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/domains/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/domains/stats/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/domains.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/domains.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/domains.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/domains/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/domains/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/domains/cgi-bin>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py .rb
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/domains/ssl/domains.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/domains/ssl/domains.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/admin/conf/web/domains/ssl/domains.ca

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-domains.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
    
    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/domains/apache2.ssl.conf_*
    IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to modify it as follows:

> 1. By default, when accessing `https://example.com`, it should point to `/cgi-bin/index.cgi`.
> 2. Redirect links that do not exist on the system to the 404 page (e.g., `https://example.com/error` or `https://example.com/error.html`). This should apply not only to `https://example.com/.pm` but also to other non-existent links.

Answer (score 0):

> When I enter a directory or file that doesn't exist on the system, it redirects to `/cgi-bin/index.cgi` instead of redirecting to the `404.html` page, as it should.

Yes, that is because you have the following rule in your `.htaccess` file:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule .* /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
> ```

This is a "front-controller pattern" that internally rewrites all requests for non-files (which includes physical directories) to `/cgi-bin/index.cgi`. This naturally overrides the `ErrorDocument 404` directive, so your `/404.html` ErrorDocument is not called.

If you only want to rewrite requests for the document root to `/cgi-bin/index.cgi` then modify the above rule like this (removing the `RewriteCond` directive entirely):

```
RewriteRule ^$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
```

Now, any request that does not map to a physical file (what you seem to be calling a "link") or a physical directory should be caught by the Apache  `ErrorDocument 404` directive.

> Only when I enter a link like `domain/errorlink.pm` does it redirect to the `404.html` error page.

Because you have a specific rule (`RewriteRule \.pm$ /404.html [L]`) that rewrites such requests. HOWEVER, this is not triggering a 404 HTTP response status, unless you have some additional server-side processing going on.

Comment: I want to express my gratitude to you for assisting me. However, I encountered an issue when I modified the rule as per your instructions, specifically the `RewriteRule ^$ /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]`. I am facing a redirection error for every other link, leading to the 404 page, even when the path exists in the system. And there's one more thing. I want to remove the .html extension from the links. However, for some links, it has been removed successfully, like [link](https://example.com/login), but for others, the .html extension is still present, such as [link](https://example.com/register.html)

Comment: @NoMore " I am facing a redirection error for every other link, leading to the 404 page, even when the path exists in the system." - That sounds like you need the front-controller pattern in order to route the requests? Do your "links" map to physical files on the filesystem? So "path" is a physical filesystem path?

Comment: @NoMore also... if your links are like `https://example.com/login` and `https://example.com/register.html`, how does this run in the `cgi-bin` directory (unless you have the appropriate directives in `.htaccess` - or server config - to rewrite the request)?